# Non-Cygwin/MSySGit Git Command-Line/GUI for Windows

Tags: git

The idea of Java implementations of GIT sounds great, but these are all embeddable APIs, not actual end-user programs. I would be happy to work even with a set of command-line programs that rely on a Java-based GIT implementation, so as to cut the Cygwin dependency. Having a GUI app on top is probably asking too much.

So to make this clear, I am looking for anything that can do what the basic `git` commands, do, e.g. `git clone`, `git init`, dare I say `git svn ...` -- on top of a non-Cygwin stack (e.g. Java/.net).

Commercial options would also work.

Comment: Msys is *not* cygwin. It's like any other native C application. There is absolutely nothing that java or .net reimplementation would give you that msys does not.

Comment: BTW: The idea of reimplementation of *anything* in *anything* is usually just one thing, *silly*. It's a waste of effort.

Comment: Anyway, care to explain why you can't use msysgit?

Comment: Hm... Git Bash looks so much like Cygwin, with its Unix style directories, "/c/...". Out of curiosity, I ran "git" from under "cmd.exe" and it seems to understand windows style directories, while it does print them out in Unix style back to you (C:/path). Well, I suppose there is nothing seriously wrong with this, but it would still be interesting to know whether there is something that looks and behaves like a native Windows console/GUI app.

Comment: MSys' goal is to provide compatibility layer for porting unix code to windows. So while the programs internally use the unixy paths, arguments are always passed in the *windows* format. So you can call MSys applications with native paths and in the MSys shell you can call native applications with the unixy paths.

Comment: Oh, `C:/path` is actually perfectly Windowsy. All the system APIs understand both forward and reverse slash, so it's perfect compromise for usability from both native applications and scripts ported from unix. The only place where you can't use forward slashes is command name in `cmd.exe`, because for dos commands, `/` introduces option even without preceding space.

Comment: *"The idea of Java implementations of GIT sounds great"* - no, it does not sound great at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that we've cleared that there is nothing terribly wrong with MSysGit as the core (yes, it can be called with windows paths from native applications and it returns the paths with forward slashes but otherwise regular windows format which works fine in most native applications), you might look at:

- The GUI that comes with MSysGit itself. It's basic, but it's actually enough 90% of time.
- [Git Cola](http://cola.tuxfamily.org/), one of the most advanced Git GUIs out there, comes with Windows installer.
- [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) is quite good Windows-only interface, that also adds a plugin in Visual Studio (last time I tried it did not show status, only provided menus). One can also use it's .Net API for calling MSysGit in their own application.
- Many more tools are listed on [Git Wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools).

Comment: Uh oh i downvoted this instead of upvoting it like I intended to. Sorry, I will just go to sleep now...

Comment: I'm very confused how this got accepted as answer when the question was about a CLI git, and all the recommendations here are GUIs... found this question by googling for windows CLI git clients, got this instead =(

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: The answer starts with saying there is nothing wrong with MSysGit. That's the standard CLI and there is really not much need for any other. The rest of the answer deals with the "Having a GUI app on top is probably asking too much." part.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Oh, and the linked wiki has both alternate CLIs and GUIs.

Comment: true, although that's not really an answer, that's more an opinion (you might think msys is just fine, but if you just need a CLI, then a 300MB msys install is quite ridiculous). The git wiki link might be useful, but it has no CLI section, and searching for cli on it doesn't yield results, so I can't make heads or tails out of how I'm supposed to find alternatives on that page.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: The ridiculous size (strangely windows explorer says 250MiB, but du says 96MiB) is because of all the copies in libexec that would be hardlinks in Unix, but Windows does not support them.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: If you are looking for alternate implementation of the same command line interface, then stop. No such things exists. There is no reason for one. If you want different, possibly easier, interface, it is the first section on the wiki page.